# PHP HTML a-element URL

Tags: php, html, get

I want to give some values with GET to another site. The value is a ID which is from a database.
The values are stored in $row.

```
 <table>
  <?php
  foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
  ?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['ID'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['Titel'];?></td>
  <td><a href='./edit.php?id=$row['ID']>Edit</a></td>
  </tr>
 <?php
}
?>
```

How do i have to concenate the string in the third td tag? I want to give the value of the ID to the next page (so the value of the first column of the matching row). I know now it is wrong concenated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td><a href='./edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID'] ?>'>Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3):

You have not put your php code inside `<?php ?>` and a closing quote for the `href` property value is also missing. Compare the corrected code below.

```
<td>
  <a href='./edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>'>Edit</a>
</td>
```